# How to generate F# signature file (without Visual Studio)

Tags: macos, f#

I' m using JetBrains Rider on MacOS and experimenting with code from Scott Wlaschin *Domain Modelling Made Functional*

Here are my module definition and it dependencies:

```
module internal DomainModeling.Domain.PlaceOrderWorkflow.Internal

open DomainModeling.Domain.Api
open DomainModeling.Domain.Primitives
open DomainModeling.Domain.Utils
```

I want to generate signature file from this module. But I'm confused of using dotnet builder or fsharp compiler. If I use dotnet command I can't pass flag **--sig**
But if I use fsharp compiler like this

```
fsharpc src/PlaceOrderWorkflow.fs --sig:PlaceOrderWorkflow.fsi
```

I get compiler errors. I think because it doesn't know about my dependencies. Errors like this

```
error FS0039: The namespace or module 'DomainModeling' is not defined.
```

So, please, tell me how to generate *.fsi in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most likely getting this error because you did not pass all source files to the F# compiler, but only a single file. To generate F# interface files, the compier needs to process the entire project, so you'd need to call `fsharpc` with all source files, but also with references to all libraries that you are depending on. If your project is anything non-trivial, this would probably be quite hard.

However, you can specify the `--sig` parameter in the normal `fsproj` project file. I just tested this and it seems to work with .NET Core too. You can do this by adding the `OtherFlags` parameter:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>    
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <OtherFlags>--sig:test.fsi</OtherFlags>
  </PropertyGroup>    
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>   
</Project>
```

When I specify this and run my project using `dotnet run` or build it using `dotnet build`, it generates the `test.fsi` file with all the interfaces. (This is for the whole project, but I don't think there is a way to restrict this to interfaces for a single file.)

Comment: Great answer. Just what I need. Thank you.