# F#: how to satisfy IStructuralEquatable requirement when implementing an exception with a signature file?

Tags: exception, compiler-errors, f#

I get a compiler error like this:

> The type definitions for type `'<ExceptionType>'` in the signature and implementation are not compatible because the signature requires that the type supports the interface `System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable` but the interface has not been implemented

I narrowed it down to the fact that my exception's record type contains a field of a function type.

In my real code, I can work around this because I don't need this function in the exception, but I'm still curious, why do I get this error **only when I have a signature file** and how would I have my exception implement `IStructuralEquatable`?

Here's my signature file, `Test.fsi`:

```ml
module Test
type exception_type
exception TestException of exception_type
val throw_test_exception: unit -> unit
```

Here's my implementation file, `Test.fs`:

```ml
module Test
type exception_type = { value: unit -> unit }
exception TestException of exception_type
let throw_test_exception (): unit =
    let r = { value = (fun () -> ()) }
    raise (TestException r)
```

When there's no signature file, everything compiles just fine.

Comment: I don't know the answer as I've never used signature files. I just wanted to point out that I've never heard of anyone in the F# community using signature files, so I would avoid using them if possible.

Comment: That is hardly an acceptable answer, no? Signature files are useful for hiding implementation. If I said, "I've never used interfaces in C#, I would avoid using them" - would that make sense?

Comment: It's not an answer, just a comment. Even if you personally find them useful, you will experience friction against F# culture by using them, which will have practical down sides and not many people will be able to help you. That is something worth considering. To put it strongly, it seems like signature files are unofficially deprecated.

Comment: I can't find any source for/discussion of signature files being unofficially deprecated. Since I didn't get any responses here about how to make my exact scenario work, I assume it's a bug or a missing feature in F#. Filed https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/10520

Answer (score 0):

For your signature to work you need to define the full type of exception_type in your signature:

test.fsi

```
module Test
type exception_type = { value: unit -> unit }
...
```

Then the error will go away.

Signature files are [typically not created by hand.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/signature-files).  You can create them [using the --sig option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781292/how-to-generate-f-signature-file-without-visual-studio).

I'm not sure why would you want to pass a function in an exception.  This does not make sense to me but if you elaborate your case (in another question), maybe I might be able to offer some suggestions.

Comment: As I said in my question, I don't actually need to pass the function in an exception. I created an exception where, as the constructor argument, I had it take my module's main record type. It happened to have a function-valued field. I determined by trial and error that it was that particular field that was causing the compilation error.

Comment: As for your suggestion, the whole point is that the exception's type in the signature file is **abstract**. If you make it concrete, you change one of the premises of my question. Abstract types is one of the reasons I'm inclined to use a signature file in the first place!

Comment: Finally, yeah, I did see that in the F# documentation, but not how to use it in the context of a .NET Core question. I just generated it - the generated signature file doesn't make any of the types abstract, so that doesn't help, either :(